# iOS notification not appearing on lockscren

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

For some reason my iOS app does not display my notification on the lockscreen

The notifications work perfectly when I use timeIntervalSinceNow...
[image]

but when I set up a time for the firedate I don't get it in the lockscreen
for some reason it gets displayed in the notification center, so the notification does get fired, just that it won't get displayed in the lockscreen.
[image]
I also get this message in the console whenever the notification is fired
[image]

from my research I know that this message is some kind of bug that happens on IOS 9, but does this have anything to do with my problem?

Here is the faulty code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var lol1: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var lol2: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func permission(sender: AnyObject) {
    let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
}


@IBAction func notificatiolol(sender: AnyObject) {

    let date:NSDateComponents = NSDateComponents()
    date.year = 2016
    date.month = 01
    date.day = 12
    date.hour = 5
    date.minute = 57
    let realDate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateFromComponents(date)


    let notification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.fireDate = realDate
    notification.alertBody = "Hey you! Yeah you! Swipe to unlock!"
    notification.alertAction = "be awesome!"
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
    notification.userInfo = ["CustomField1": "w00t"]
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
}
```

}

and here is the code that works

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var lol1: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var lol2: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func permission(sender: AnyObject) {
    let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
}


@IBAction func notificatiolol(sender: AnyObject) {



    let notification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 5)
    notification.alertBody = "Hey you! Yeah you! Swipe to unlock!"
    notification.alertAction = "be awesome!"
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
    notification.userInfo = ["CustomField1": "w00t"]
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
}
```

}

Thank you in advance, and sorry if this question is a duplicate

Comment: is the date in "faulty code" specified in the correct timezone? did you make sure that the time is correct (hour and minute is later than the moment when notification is scheduled)?

Comment: @parametr Not its not. By default `NSDateComponents` timeZone is set to nil

Comment: @ parametr thanks for the comment, but putting the NSTimezone in the code unfortunately did not improve the situation